# Keyboard Pressing Application

Tags: keyboard, automation

Imagine that problem. When you play some games, sometimes happens situations like "press quickly the X key to escape from ropes" or "press quickly the X key to fill the rage gauge", etc.

Of course, that kind of game destroy keyboards, joysticks, mouses, etc.

I would like to know about programs (preferentially free) that, by example, will press the 'x' key in intervals of, by example, 300ms.

Remember that the built in Windows "keyboard repeat rate" doesn't works for games. When you press (and hold) somekey in the game, the key is not repeated as in default Windows Applications.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[AutoPressKey](http://www.sobolsoft.com/autopresskey/) will do it for you I believe.

[image]